# why is my wav file not playing in my console app

Tags: c#

My wav file is not playing when all my research show similar way like below. Volume is turned up too.

```
using System.Media;

namespace PlayingSystemSounds
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\mypath\new.wav");
            
            simpleSound.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me guess, the program just exits?

Comment: My guess is that the program is just exiting since there's nothing left for it to do after `Play()`. Maybe try adding `Console.ReadLine()` to force to keep it open (I'm not familiar with that SoundPlayer class, so there might be better ways to do this)

Comment: That is likely playing _asynchronously_ so you need to have your program wait til it completes (or long enough). Might want to try `PlaySync()` instead?

Comment: [SoundPlayer.PlaySync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.playsync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SoundPlayer.Play()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.play?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) is a non-blocking method. From the documentation (emphasis mine)

> Plays the .wav file **using a new thread**, and loads the .wav file first if it has not been loaded.

There's no code after `.Play()` executes, which means your application terminates immediately after the program starts to play the sound.

Use `.PlaySync()` instead, OR you need a way of keeping the program running after executing `.Play()`, such as with a `Console.ReadLine()`, Sleeping/Delaying the thread, or switching to an event based framework like Winforms or WPF.